# Looping and Counting w/find

Tags: python

So I am working diligently on some examples for my homework and came across yet another error.

The original:

```
    word = 'banana'
    count = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == 'a':
            count = count + 1
    print count
```

Ok. Looks simple.

I then used this code in a function name *count* and generalized it so that it accepts the string and the letter as argument.

```
    def count1(str, letter):
        count = 0             
        word = str            
        for specific_letter in word: 
            if specific_letter == letter: 
                count = count + 1 

        print count
```

This is where I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have to rewrite this function so that instead of traversing the string, it uses the three-parameter version of find from the previous section. Which this is:

```
    def find(word, letter, startat):
        index = startat
        while index <= len(word):
            if word[index] == letter:
                return index
            index = index + 1


        return -1
```

This is how far I got... but the program doesn't work the way I want it to.

```
    def find(str, letter, startat):
        index = startat
        word = str   
        count = 0
        while index <= len(word):
            if word[index] == letter:
                for specific_letter in word:
                    if specific_letter == letter:
                        count = count + 1

                print count
            index = index + 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. I want to understand what I'm doing instead of just given the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The point of the exercise is to use the previously defined function `find` as a building block to implement a new function `count`.  So, where you're going wrong is by trying to redefine `find`, when you should be trying to change the implementation of `count`.

However, there is a wrinkle in that `find` as you have given has a slight error, you would need to change the `<=` to a `<` in order for it to work properly.  With a `<=`, you could enter the body of the loop with `index == len(word)`, which would cause `IndexError: string index out of range`.

So fix the `find` function first:

```
def find(word, letter, startat):
    index = startat
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index = index + 1
    return -1
```

And then re-implement `count`, this time using `find` in the body:

```
def count(word, letter):
    result = 0
    startat = 0
    while startat < len(word):
        next_letter_position = find(word, letter, startat)
        if next_letter_position != -1:
            result += 1
            startat = next_letter_position + 1
        else:
            break
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use find to find you the next index of the given letter.

In your code you don't use the find function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try something interesting and pythonic:  Change the original `find` to `yield index` and remove the final `return -1`.  Oh, and fix the `<=` bug:

```
def find(word, letter, startat):
    index = startat
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            yield index
        index = index + 1

print list(find('hello', 'l', 0))
```

Now `find` returns *all* of the results.  You can use it like I did in the example or with a `for position in find(...):`  You can also simply write `count` in terms of the length of the result.

(Sorry, no hints on the final function in your question because I can't tell what you're trying to do.  Looks like maybe you left in too much of the original function and jumbled their purposes together?)

Comment: @ Ben Jackson What I'm trying to do is pick a spot(index) on the string and count how many of the selected 'letter' from that point up. At least, that's how I'm reading what the exercise is asking me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:  This should work.

```
def find(word, letter, startat)
    index = startat
    count = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
           count = count + 1  ##This counts when letter matches the char in word
    index = index + 1
print count



>>> find('banana', 'a', 0)
3
>>> find('banana', 'n', 0)
2
>>> find('mississippi', 's', 0)
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
def find_count(srch_wrd, srch_char, startlookingat):
counter = 0
index = startlookingat
while index < len(srch_wrd):     
    if srch_wrd[index] == srch_char:
        counter += 1
    index += 1 
return counter`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_letter2(f, l):

    count = 0
    t = 0

    while t < len(f):
        np = f.find(l, t)
        if np != -1:
            count += 1
            t = np + 1
            "I was wrong by  doing t =t +1"
        else:
            break
    return count


print(count_letter2("banana", "a"))

print(count_letter2("abbbb", "a"))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).